# Appropriate way to respond to unsupported HTTP requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, response, rails-routing

For an API-only app, I'm thinking of verifying incoming HTTP request with a `before_action`, e.g.:

```
# Returns a 405 status for unsupported HTTP methods.
def verify_post_request
  head :method_not_allowed unless request.post?
end
```

But I'm not fond of having to create extra routes to handle every unsupported HTTP method. Without the extra routes, the app returns 404 for unsupported requests as no matching route can be found. Having all those extra "unused" routes seems like a code smell.

What's the best practice here? Is it better to

- Have routes for supported methods you support, and 404 otherwise
- Have routes for all methods so that unsupported ones respond with a more informative 405

The former seems better for the maintainer (cleaner code), while the latter seems better for the user (descriptive feedback).

Comment: I don't see any reason for doing this. It's extra work or something that's not part of the application. If I have `resource :user` defined in my routes, why would I want to have 20+ more lines defining all of the other combinations of request types and paths that are implicitly defined by `resource`?

Comment: @Jon, having routes for the other HTTP methods allows you to return a more accurate response IMO. For example, if someone makes a request using PUT instead of PATCH, your app can respond with a more informative 405 "Method not supported" instead of 404 "Not found".

In terms of number of lines, you don't necessarily need more lines depending on how you route. E.g. `match '/foo/bar/action', to: 'foo/bar#action', via: [:get, :post]` vs `match '/foo/bar/action', to: 'foo/bar#action', via: :all`

Comment: I've written something like 20 RoR applications.  This has never mattered.  If someone's using the wrong HTTP method then they're doing something weird or wrong with your application and there's no reason to cater to them.  I know that sounds harsh, but as long as users are using your links and forms and you have it configured correctly and test coverage to ensure that - in other words, a normal application - it won't add anything to your users' experiences to give them more detailed errors if they try to somehow use the wrong verb to access a page.

Comment: To use a phrase that I didn't create but I think is appropriate - you're failing to solve a problem that doesn't exist.

Comment: I disagree with some comments here. You can, and should return 405 if you issue f.i. ```POST /user/1``` instead of ```GET /user/1```. In other ways you are saying, "yes there is **resource** ```/user/1```, but you are not allowed to make POST request on that resource. We are talking here about **API only** app, which should have api behaviour, and not navigational nehaviour (like general ror app).

Comment: @MichaelChaney I've edited my question to clarify that I'm building an API-only app, so there won't be any users interacting with the app through a browser. Does that change your perspective?

Comment: No, my perspective remains unchanged.

Comment: Is there a solution to this yet?

Comment: @Jwan622 there's no clear answer, but in practice you would see 404s more often than 405s in this situation. The argument is that the extra effort is not worth it for such a minor distinction, your app is still usable. Another argument is that adding the extra routes can be misleading to others viewing the routes file or the output of `rails/rake routes`, because at a glance it looks like your resources support more actions than it actually does.

Answer (score 4):

I would go with having routes for methods you support and 404 otherwise.
I think your application should only repond to routes it needs to, and leave every other route.

There is no need to provide more informative responses. A not existing route is a 404 route and nothing more.

Comment: I'd like to point out to readers that this answer was added before I made my edit clarifying that it's an API-only app. This is a very important distinction that I accidentally left out. It means that response codes matter a lot more since the amount of feedback is limited. That said, I didn't upvote this answer because I find it lacks an argument. Why do you think there is no need to provide more informative responses?

Comment: One of the things that specifies a route is the http verb. `POST /user/1` is different from `GET /user/1`. Suppose you only have `POST /user/:id` and a user hits `GET /user/1` (API, browser, etc). Since you don't have `GET /user/:id`, so that route does not exist and is not found, and should be 404.